# Slide down menu with check boxes in android

Tags: android, list, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I've been looking around and searching all over the internet on how to do this. I am really baffled here because I don't think this is a built-in widget for the android API. What I am trying to build is a "list" of items that when an item is clicked, it shows a series of check boxes below it. An example on my EVO is the "News" application when you go to "Add Feeds". I'll try and draw it out here:

```
BEFORE NEWS IS PRESSED:

News       >

AFTER NEWS IS PRESSED:

News       (arrow points down)
   CNN.com      (checkbox)
   Yahoo.com    (checkbox)
```

I'm sure this has to be custom made but I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Here are the links to the images:

Before: 
[image: http://img705.imageshack.us/i/newsbefore.png/]

After: 
[image: http://img845.imageshack.us/i/newsafter.png/]

Comment: You might want to consider using DDMS to take a screenshot. If you cannot add it to the question directly (not sure if there are limits on that for newcomers to StackOverflow), host it somewhere like ImageShack and link to the image.

Comment: I can't upload any images...because I'm new :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, that's just a `ListView`. Each rounded rectangle is a row in the `ListView`. When you click the arrow `ImageButton`, it makes a bunch of `CheckedTextView` widgets in a vertical `LinearLayout` visible.

Comment: Okay so it's not as hard as I thought lol...I'll give that a try and come back to you all if I can't figure it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: Actually I just figured out that this is an ExpandableListView...very simple built in thing to the SDK. Here is their example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Comment: @Todd Vrba: Ah! I've never seen one used with `CheckedTextViews` at the child level, and `ExpandableListView` not all that popular of a widget in the first place. Still, though, I apologize for steering you the wrong way.